# How to set charset to particular column in migration of Yii2

Tags: character-encoding, yii2, migration

I have a migration in Yii2, where I try create a table. I set charset for table, but I don't know how to set charset for particular column.

For example:

```
$this->createTable('some_table', [
            'column_1' => $this->string(64)->notNull(),
            'column_2' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
            'column_3' => $this->integer(),
        ], 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB');
```

In above code I want to set charset "utf8-unicode-ci" for column_1.
How to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use append().

```
$this->createTable('some_table', [
    'column_1' => $this->string(64)->notNull()->append('CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci'),
    'column_2' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
    'column_3' => $this->integer(),
], 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB');
```

Is it just an example? Because you don't have to set charset for a single column when it's the same as for the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you can use the following trick:

```
$schema = $this->getDb()->getSchema();
$columnBase = $schema->createColumnSchemaBuilder($schema::TYPE_STRING, 255);
$columnExtension = $schema->createColumnSchemaBuilder('CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin');
$columnExtension->notNull();

$this->createTable('{{%table1}}', [
    'column1' => $columnBase . ' ' . $columnExtension,
]);
```